# Android thread that sends data from different Fragment

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a Fragment that connets to various sensors using bluetooth. My Activity should periodically (say at 50-100Hz) send the data to some server.

My Fragment has a `List<SensorState> sensorStates` which contains the desired data, populated on the Fragment when through a bluetooth sensor API call. On my activity I created a `HandlerThread` which executes every 100ms using `postDelayed`. 
This thread basically has a reference to `sensorStates` (I get it when main Activity's `onCreate()` is called) and iterates through the `sensorStates` building a string representation and outputing to console using `Log.d`.

The problem is that I see that the desired member `sensorStates.data` which is populated in the Fragment, is null, so I think that I cannot see it from the `HandlerThread` and that communication should be done in a different way.

How should an underlying process, which should run "precisely" at 100Hz get data that is generated in a different thread?

Comment: Can you use the EventBus model? http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Comment: I don't know it, thanks for pointing out. I would prefer some native solution. I guess it will a) have less overhead (remember I want to send data at 50-100Hz) and b) won't need to add a new dependency into my project.